# How to derive Excel data in SSIS regardless of excel column name?

Tags: excel, ssis

I have a SQL integration package that pulls data from Excel and loads it into SQL. As part of this integration I have an Excel source in my Data Flow that pulls cells from Excel sheets using the below SQL command text in the Connection Manager:

```
SELECT * FROM [Data$E8:AI9]
```

This has been able to succesfully grab the data that I'm after which is located on A8:AI19, however there's been a problem in regards to the Data Flow Task. The 'column names' for my data which are located on E8:EI9 are irregular and sometimes change. When this occurs it causes validation errors with the package run. Is there a way I can configure my Data flow task to retreive data from the specified ranges regardless of the column names?

My Data Flow consists of an Excel Source > Data Conversion > OLE DB Destination.

Comment: Ignore headers, but your results will be F1, F2 ... and you can deal with that or rename each one.

Comment: How do I ignore the headers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first option to do this is in the connection manager:

[image]

But I am also pretty sure you can set that on either the columns tab or the advanced tab. I don't have access to SSIS right now to be sure.